# Copy of object in accessor method

Tags: java, object

If you return an object in an accessor method which is stored in a field, based on
what do you decide whether you return a copy of that object?

Comment: Some literature on immutability [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the object is *immutable*, you can normally return this without making a copy. Beyond that, I would consider:

1. the clients I'm returning it to. Am I returning it exclusively to clients I understand/trust etc. such that I know how they're going to use this object ? If so, I would perhaps not make a copy
2. how expensive is it to make a copy ? If it's trivial, I may default to making a copy.
3. Am *I* likely to change this object, having returned a reference to a client ? If so I would make a copy

There's no hard-and-fast solution. It's determined by a number of criteria. If I'm building a set of objects that interact heavily and those interactions are understood and not likely to expand, then I tend to default to not copying. If I'm making objects available to clients whose usage I don't understand, or creating an API for long-term future use, then I would default to copying.

If you have objects that are mutable, but you don't want clients changing, you can also restrict how the clients interact with those objects by restricting them via the interface you return those objects by (e.g. return them a read-only interface to this object). It won't help them if you mutate that object under the covers, but it will stop them changing an object via the reference you've given them. If the the object won't change behind the scenes, it's less work than continually producing copies.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, an accessor ( `public Object getField();` ) always returns the pointer to the field itself. It doesn't copy any object, the object exists only once in the memory, and the method returns only the pointer to it.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on how you've implemented that method ?

Comment: If you are the implementor of the getter, it does. I was of thinking that the question asks whether do accessors return objects' copy (in a regular case). Maybe I didn't understand the question right.

Answer (score 1):

if u don't want anyone make change to a mutable object, return a copy of that object. but if this object is immutable like instance of Class Font, Color.. or a primitive type like int, double.. the client can't make any change to this reference